# Apply the checked event when loading in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a small change to the code at http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/bcbxftr6/1/ to display the checked event by default:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="notice" checked /><label>Featured</label>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li class="top">Tea</li>
  <li class="top">Milk</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ol>
```

jQuery:

```
var oldHtml = $('ol').html();
var reversed = false;

  $('.notice').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $.each($('li.top').get().reverse(), function(index, value) {
      $(value).insertBefore($('li')[0]);
    });
    reversed = true;
    $('li.top').show();
    return;
  }

  $('ol').html(oldHtml);
  reversed = false;
  $('li.top').hide();
});
```

(Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bcbxftr6/80/)

The problem with the code is that the checked event is not applied when loading. When I click two or more times, it works as expected.

How can it be modified to load the page with the checked event applied?

If there is anything unclear, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but may be loading the script whiting the 
`$( document ).ready()`
 function will do the magic :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I use "$( document ).ready()", for example?

Comment: ///function on the html header 

    $(document).ready(function(){

    ////your code here

    })

Comment: I think my code has a problem. I will take time to look into it. Really thanks for your help.

Comment: answer doesn't really have any bearing on question

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is trigger the change event after you create the event handler

```
$('.notice').change(function () {
    // your event handling code
     ......

   /* now trigger the event */
}).change();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bcbxftr6/81/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just run the function once without conditions, like this....

```
var oldHtml = $('ol').html();
var reversed = false;

  var changefunc = function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $.each($('li.top').get().reverse(), function(index, value) {
      $(value).insertBefore($('li')[0]);
    });
    reversed = true;
    $('li.top').show();
    return;
  }
  $('.notice').change(changefunc); 
  changefunc(); // Just run it once....

  $('ul').html(oldHtml);
  reversed = false;
  $('li.top').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Soren.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering `.change()` event at page load

```
var oldHtml = $('ol').html();
var reversed = false;

  $('.notice').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $.each($('li.top').get().reverse(), function(index, value) {
      $(value).insertBefore($('li')[0]);
    });
    reversed = true;
              $('li.top').show();
    return;
  }

  $('ul').html(oldHtml);
  reversed = false;
      $('li.top').hide();
})
// call `.change()` on `.notice`
.change();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bcbxftr6/82/

Comment: I think my code has a problem. I will take time to look into it. Thanks again for your help.